# Why jQuery's Promise.reject does not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, promise

I am working with REST API, similar to this stub: [Snippet 1](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1687097) (Ruby on Rails example).

I have existing jQuery-code on classic callbacks: [Snippet 2](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1687096)

which is executes with logs:

```
case 1:
[INFO] /api/my/action1: got rejecting signal, do not continue 

case 2:
[INFO] /api/my/action1: no rejecting signal, continue
[INFO] /api/my/action2: no rejecting signal, continue
[INFO] /api/my/action3: hurrah!! we got message:  Third action executed!

case 3:
[INFO] /api/my/action1: no rejecting signal, continue
[ERROR] Got error with message: Unexpected error
```

I want to refactor this code to promises:

```
function ajxGet(url){
  return $.ajax({
    url,
    dataType: 'JSON'
  })
}

export function makeThreeAsyncQueries(){
  ajxGet('/api/my/action1')
    .then(response1 => {
      if(response1.do_reject_other_actions){
        console.log('[INFO] /api/my/action1: got rejecting signal, do not continue');
        return Promise.reject({mute: true});
      }else{
        console.log('[INFO] /api/my/action1: no rejecting signal, continue');
        return ajxGet('/api/my/action2');
      }
    })
    .then(response2 => {
      if(response2.do_reject_other_actions){
        console.log('[INFO] /api/my/action2: got rejecting signal, do not continue');
        return Promise.reject({mute: true});
      }else{
        console.log('[INFO] /api/my/action2: no rejecting signal, continue');
        return ajxGet('/api/my/action3');
      }
    })
    .then(response3 => {
      console.log('[INFO] /api/my/action3: hurrah!! we got message: ', response3.message);
    })
    .fail((err) => {
      if(err && err.mute){
        console.log('[INFO] normal chain break.');
        return
      }
      console.info('[ERROR] Got error with message:', err.responseJSON.message);
    });
}
```

The problem is that `Promise.reject({mute: true});` does not working, and I have these logs:

```
[INFO] /api/my/action1: got rejecting signal, do not continue           <<-- SHOULD STOP HERE
[INFO] /api/my/action2: no rejecting signal, continue
   Uncaught (in promise) Object {mute: true}
   <...callstack here...>
[INFO] /api/my/action3: hurrah!! we got message:  Third action executed!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you are using [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) from [ECMAScript 2015 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-objects) instead of jQuery's [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) promise-like object.

So instead of this line:

```
return Promise.reject({mute: true});
```

Use this:

```
return $.Deferred().reject({ mute: true })
```

Full example of code:

```
function ajxGet(url){
  return $.ajax({
    url,
    dataType: 'JSON'
  })
}

export function makeThreeAsyncQueries(){
  ajxGet('/api/my/action1')
    .then(response1 => {
      if(response1.do_reject_other_actions){
        console.log('[INFO] /api/my/action1: got rejecting signal, do not continue');
        return $.Deferred().reject({ mute: true })
      }else{
        console.log('[INFO] /api/my/action1: no rejecting signal, continue');
        return ajxGet('/api/my/action2');
      }
    })
    .then(response2 => {
      if(response2.do_reject_other_actions){
        console.log('[INFO] /api/my/action2: got rejecting signal, do not continue');
        return $.Deferred().reject({ mute: true })
      }else{
        console.log('[INFO] /api/my/action2: no rejecting signal, continue');
        return ajxGet('/api/my/action3');
      }
    })
    .then(response3 => {
      console.log('[INFO] /api/my/action3: hurrah!! we got message: ', response3.message);
    })
    // as argument here we will get jquery's xhr object on AJAX-error, or will get payload sent by $.deferred().reject
    .fail((xhr) => {
      if(xhr && xhr.mute){
        console.log('[INFO] normal chain break.');
        return
      }
      console.info('[ERROR] Got error with message:', xhr.responseJSON.message);
    });
}
```

So when backend will return `do_reject_other_actions === true` chain will break and you will get this correct logs:

```
[INFO] /api/my/action1: got rejecting signal, do not continue
[INFO] normal chain break.

or

[INFO] /api/my/action1: no rejecting signal, continue
[INFO] /api/my/action2: got rejecting signal, do not continue
[INFO] normal chain break.

or

[INFO] /api/my/action1: no rejecting signal, continue
[INFO] /api/my/action2: no rejecting signal, continue
[INFO] /api/my/action3: hurrah!! we got message:  Third action executed!

or

[INFO] /api/my/action1: no rejecting signal, continue
[ERROR] Got error with message: Unexpected error
```

## SOLUTION 2

If you want to use [ECMAScript2015 Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), you can wrap jQuery's `ajax` into [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```
function ajxGet(url){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax({
      url,
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: response => resolve(response),
      error: (xhr) => { reject(xhr) },
    })
  });
}

export function makeThreeAsyncQueries(){
  ajxGet('/api/my/action1')
    .then(response1 => {
      if(response1.do_reject_other_actions){
        console.log('[INFO] /api/my/action1: got rejecting signal, do not continue');
        return Promise.reject({mute: true});
      }else{
        console.log('[INFO] /api/my/action1: no rejecting signal, continue');
        return ajxGet('/api/my/action2');
      }
    })
    .then(response2 => {
      if(response2.do_reject_other_actions){
        console.log('[INFO] /api/my/action2: got rejecting signal, do not continue');
        return Promise.reject({mute: true});
      }else{
        console.log('[INFO] /api/my/action2: no rejecting signal, continue');
        return ajxGet('/api/my/action3');
      }
    })
    .then(response3 => {
      console.log('[INFO] /api/my/action3: hurrah!! we got message: ', response3.message);
    })
    .catch((xhr) => {
      if(xhr && xhr.mute){
        console.log('[INFO] normal chain break.');
        return
      }
      console.info('[ERROR] Got error with message:', xhr.responseJSON.message);
    });
}
```

Note that instead of `fail(...)` you will need to use `catch(...)` at the end of chain, because [`fail`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) is jQuery Deferred's method.